# How to pass empty args to Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I tried to pass blank command line arguments in a Netbeans Java project using Properties-->Run-->Arguments with "" or '' but nothing.
I have some arguments that some times have to be empty or null.

Answer (score 2):

The common way to handle that is to **not specify arguments when they are blank or empty**. It is quite the norm in the CLI/scripting world to work like this. Unspecified arguments mean either to use the defaults or no value.

Aside there are Java nice libraries to help you parse your program `options` or arguments, such as:

- **Args4j** http://args4j.kohsuke.org/
- **Apache CLI** http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/

---

### EDIT

Additonal remarks:

- Without a smarter options/arguments parser, it is not possible to handle empty arguments properly (i.e. just by setting a blank, whitespace or quoted empty string). The only way to achieve that would be to define a keyword or special character in order to identify empty/unspecified arguments when processing `args[]`.
- This behavior is not bound to Netbeans. Rather it relates to how Java parses the `varargs` of the `main()` method from the command-line.

Interesting links:

- [What is "String args[]"? parameter in main method Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890966/what-is-string-args-parameter-in-main-method-java)
- [How to handle empty parameters in a main method java call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761043/how-to-handle-empty-parameters-in-a-main-method-java-call)

Comment: In netbeans args are separated by a blank character between them. So to not specify an argument must have two consecutive blank characters. I tried it. Nothing.

Comment: You will need to use one the mentionned libraries to achieve that. Clearly if you are using rawly the args from the `main()` method, none of them can be null or empty. Without a clever parsing, you will not be able to achieve great things with your arguments or options. I strongly recommend you investigate the given links. It is extremely easy to use.

Comment: To say it differently: nothing (including blanks, whitespaces, quotes) will help you in dealing with empty/unspecified arguments. You have to work with well-formated options and common parsers, or define a constant for empty values (such as `NIL`) and compare given args against this constant to determine if the argument is legal/valid or should be treated as empty/unspecified.

Comment: @nonlinearly - I agree with bsaverino. It is well worth a small investment of time to use a command line parser, for this situation.

Comment: Also I'm so disappointed with SO... It makes such a big fuss about something so simple...Sometimes it gives me the impression that it wants the questions to have the answers. If so it makes no sense

Comment: Not sure to understand what you mean, but yeah this is not a forum here.